# JQuery mobile adding own CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to add a background image for my JQuery mobile page and I have my external CSS. The background image only appears if I remove the JQuery scripts. How could I continue using my own css without the JQuery scripts interfering? I would also like to use the JQuery buttons etc using my CSS

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Find me</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/findme.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- background not showing up here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

External CSS

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: you could use **!important** in your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing "body" selector to ".ui-page" selector in your css file and adding !important:

```
.ui-page {
    background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg") !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    -webkit-background-size:cover !important;
    -moz-background-size:cover !important;
    -o-background-size:cover !important;
    background-size:cover !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Leave the scripts in place.
2. Load the page and inspect the `body` element.
3. Find out what CSS rule gives it the `background-image` property.
4. Build a stronger CSS selector in your own CSS.

If you have any trouble with the steps above:

5. Replicate your problem in a jsfiddle and update your question, I'll build the selector for you.

   ---

UPDATE:

Neither of the following resources

- `https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css`,
- `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`
- `https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js`

are setting the `background-image` property of the `body` element. This means that it is set inside the `css/findme.css` which you have not provided.

Please add the contents of `css/findme.css` in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahyrn286/), save it and update your question with the resulting link.

Comment: I just want to know how you can change the styling, like an example

Comment: @user122938221: [Basics](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). [Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_examples.asp).

Comment: If you have trouble adding CSS to your page, [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Comment: Ive used the selector and the background image still doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your scripts is overriding the `body` styles.  You could create a background `div` that covers the body to simulate a full-page background, though.

Example HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="background">
  </div>
</body>
```

Example CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

#background {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: For some reason the background image still doesn't appear

Comment: It does when I add content

Comment: instead of `min-height`, try just `height` - the background div will be at minimum the height of the body.  also,  add the html element to the selector

Comment: Its only when I add content inside the <div> the background image appears and depending on how much content too, it displays it bit by bit. By default when the page loads the image doesn't appear

Comment: Instead, we can make it a fixed position element